# items not displaying in titanium TableViewRow

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm creating a variation on the simple Titanium Book sample app.
I'm launching the app on an attached Nexus 7.
The app launches, but my sample data is not displayed.
I can't see what's causing it to fail.

Index.xml is as follows:

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="item"/> 
    <TabGroup>
        <Tab title="Items" icon="KS_nav_ui.png"> -->
            <Window class="container" title="Items">
                <!-- Add TableView and  TableViewRow -->
                <TableView dataCollection="item">
                    <TableViewRow label="{label}" description="{description}" onClick="showItem"></TableViewRow>
                </TableView>
                <Menu id="menu" platform="android">
                    <MenuItem
                    title="Add book"
                    onClick="addBook"
                    showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM" />
                </Menu>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab title="Admin" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window title="Manage your listings">
                <Label>Table of stuff to manage</Label>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Indix.js

```
var myItems = Alloy.Collections.item;

//Create some sample items so that we have something to style.
//This will eventually grab data from the bootstrap sync method.
var item1 = Alloy.createModel('item', {
            taken_by: 0,
            taken_time: 0,
            label: 'Attivo Maestro',
            creator: 1,
            enabled: 1,
            location: 1,
            description: "Today the Maestro model is the most technologically advanced ski on the market. It represents the big news for skiers looking for maximum performance uphill and downhill. Attivo shock absorber technology makes the difference.",
            created: "2015-02-14 13:19:21",
            image: "http://skitrab.com/upload/products_/158/attivo_skis.jpg",
            price: 1,
            currentPrice: 765,
            topic: 1,
            deleted: 0
        });

myItems.add(item1);
item1.save();

function showItem(event) {
    var selectedItem = event.source;
    var args = {
        label : selectedItem.label,
        description : selectedItem.description
    };
    var Itemview = Alloy.createController("Itemdetails", args).getView();

    if (OS_IOS) {
        $.navGroupWin.openWindow(Itemview);
    }
    if (OS_ANDROID) {
        Itemview.open();
    }
}

function addItem(){
    var myAddItem = Alloy.createController("addItem",{}).getView();
    if (OS_IOS) {
        $.navGroupWin.openWindow(myAddItem);
    }
    if (OS_ANDROID) {
        myAddItem.open();
    }
}
$.index.open();
```

item.js:

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns: {
            "taken_by": "integer",
            "taken_time": "integer",
            "label": "text",
            "creator": "integer",
            "enabled": "integer",
            "location": "integer",
            "description": "text",
            "created": "text",
            "image": "text",
            "price": "integer",
            "currentPrice": "integer",
            "topic": "integrer",
            "deleted": "text"
        },
        adapter: {
            idAttribute: "itemid",
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "item"
        }
    },
    extendModel: function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

It all seems fine to me and compiles without any errors.  There are some warnings that don't seem relevant but they are:

```
[WARN] :   linker: libstlport_shared.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[WARN] :   linker: libtiverify.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[WARN] :   linker: libkroll-v8.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [308,465] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
[WARN] :   V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [174,174] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
```

It's loads onto the nexus, the splash screen appears, then the app starts with two tabs, however there is no content in tab1, which I believe should have an item label and description.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was simple in the end.  In the titanium tutorial, they have an example called Favebooks, where the book has a title and an author.

To display the title within the TableViewRow you do the following (in their example)

```
<TableViewRow title="{title}" author="{author}" onClick="showItem"></TableViewRow>
```

I modified this for my own purposes.  I had an item with a label and a description and it seems natural to change the TableViewRow line to read

```
<TableViewRow label="{label}" description="{description}" onClick="showItem"></TableViewRow>
```

However, this doesn't work, you need to put

```
<TableViewRow title="{label}" description="{description}" onClick="showItem"></TableViewRow>
```

It seems that the book title and the TableViewRow title are two different things.  Hope that helps someone...